# E-mail notifications with server filter across devices

Tags: email, exchange, evolution

I have what seems like a trivial problem:

1. I have an Exchange mail account from my university.
2. I want to automatically sort incoming mails into sub-folders.
3. I want to receive notifications for new mail at least on my Android phone, preferably on my laptop and desktop, too. (I am using Evolution as my preferred mail client.)

My current setup is that I used the outlook web application to filter my mails on the server since a mail client on either laptop or desktop will not be running all the time.

The problem is that both **Evolution and my phone's Gmail client will not generate notifications for new mail that is not in the Inbox folder**.
In Evolution I have checked that all folders are searched for new mails, similarly on my phone I have selected all folders for synchronization.
I do receive new mails in all folders, it is just that I don't get notifications for the still unread mails already sorted into folders other than my inbox.

Is there something I am missing? Are the Outlook Web App filters somehow screwing with the mails, suppressing notifications or is this just a problem of both my mail clients? I would switch to another mail app on my phone but I do like Evolution and would like to keep it as my main mail client.

Versions:

- Evolution 3.46.3
- Android 12
- Gmail 2022.11.13

One of the filter rules in the web app:

[image: Filter Screenshot]

Comment: >My current setup is that I used the outlook web application to filter my mails on the server since a mail client on either laptop or desktop will not be running all the time. How did you filter your mails in OWA? By creating a rule? If so, please provide a screenshot about your rule for our better research.

Comment: Yes exactly, I created an inbox rule. I've included a screenshot in my post. I've thought that merely moving the mail to another folder while keeping it unread should trigger the other client's new mail notifications. Is there possibly some additional flag used by outlook to mark an e-mail as new?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that all clients (including desktop clients, web apps, and mobile apps) are not receiving notifications? When this rule is not applied, will you be notified that the mail arrives at Inbox?

Comment: Yes exactly. When the mails are not sorted by this rule, all of my clients generate a notification. When the rule is active, none of them (Android Gmail and Evolution on three different systems) do.